# Let $D$ be a subset of $L^2[0,1]$ defined in the following way

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

any help with this problem, it gave me hard time:

Let $D$ be a subset of $L^2[0,1]$ defined in the following way: A function
$f$ belongs to $D$ if and only if f is equal almost everywhere to a function
$g$ that is absolutely continuous on $[0, 1]$, $g(0) = g(1)$, and $g' \in L^2[0,1]$.
Let $T$ be the operator defined on $D$ by $T(f) = g'$.

1- Prove that $T$ is well defined?
2- Prove that $T$ is closed?

any help is appreciated, thanx in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $T(g) = g'$?

Comment: Nope it is as above!

Comment: I see now.  My mistake!

Comment: Can you supply the definition of a closed operator?

Answer (score 2):

**For the first part of the problem:**

---

Suppose $g,h$ are two absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that $f$ is equal almost everywhere both to $g$ and $h$ with $g',h'\in L^{2}[0,1]$.

We need to show that $g' = h'$ almost everywhere.

Suppose for a contradiction that there is a closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $g'(x)\neq h'(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Can you use the mean value theorem to get a contradiction?

I also overlooked the fact that we need to show that $g'$ exists and is in $L^{2}[0,1]$.  This is where absolute continuity will be needed.

---

**For the second part:**

---

**Note:**  Something must be wrong in the argument below here because the hypothesis that $g(0) = g(1)$ for all $g\in D$ was used nowhere in this argument.)

Let $(f_{n}, T(f_{n}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of points in $D\oplus L^{2}[0,1]$ such that $(f_{n},T(f_{n}))\to (f,g)$ for some $f\in D$, $g\in L^{2}[0,1]$.  We need to show that $T(f) = g$.

Choose absolutely continuous functions $F$ and $(F_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ on $[0,1]$ such that $F_{n} = f_{n}$ almost everywhere and $F = f$ almost everywhere.

I *think* this is the argument.
\begin{align*}
\|T(f) - g\|_{2}^{2} &= \|T(f) - \lim_{n\to\infty}T(f_{n})\|_{2}^{2}\\
                 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\|F' - T(f_{n})\|_{2}^{2}\\
                 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\|F' - F_{n}'\|_{2}^{2}\\
                 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}|F'(t) - F_{n}'(t)|^{2}dt\\
                 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left|\lim_{s\to t}\frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t - s} - \lim_{s\to t}\frac{F_{n}(t) - F_{n}(s)}{t - s}\right|^{2}dt\\
                 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{s\to t}\left|\frac{F(t) - F(s)}{t - s} - \frac{F_{n}(t) - F_{n}(s)}{t - s}\right|^{2}dt\\
                 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{s\to t}\left|\frac{F(t) - F_{n}(t)}{t - s} - \frac{F(s) - F_{n}(s)}{t - s}\right|^{2}dt\\
                 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{s\to t}\int_{0}^{1}\left|\frac{F(t) - F_{n}(t)}{t - s} - \frac{F(s) - F_{n}(s)}{t - s}\right|^{2}dt\\
                 &\stackrel{\color{red}{(!)}}= \lim_{s\to t}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left|\frac{F(t) - F_{n}(t)}{t - s} - \frac{F(s) - F_{n}(s)}{t - s}\right|^{2}dt\\
                 &\stackrel{\color{blue}{(!)}}= \lim_{s\to t}\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{F(t) - F_{n}(t)}{t - s} - \frac{F(s) - F_{n}(s)}{t - s}\right|^{2}dt\\
                 &= 0
\end{align*}
and thus $T$ is closed.

There are still some details to fill in.  The $\color{blue}{(!)}$ step can be done with a standard application of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, which I will leave to you.  The $\color{red}{(!)}$ *should* involve a uniform convergence argument.  I am being vague with this last part -- I confess I still don't know exactly if/why we can switch these limits, but I will sleep on it and hopefully have more insight tomorrow (or we will see another answer!).

Good luck!

Comment: by MVT we will get that $f(a) \ne f(a)$? or the same values for $f$ are not equal!!?

Comment: Try choosing a closed subinterval of $[a,b]$ upon which $f = g = h$.

Comment: will the subset of $[0,1]$ have measure $0$!!

Comment: Can you ask your question more precisely?

Comment: What you have said above is the definition of $T$ being continuous.

Comment: ok, I'm trying to understand your hint, but you lost me!! don't get me wrong I'm grateful for your help! yeah sorry  it is like this for a closed operator $T$ we must have for any $f_n \to f$ in $D$ and $T(f_n) \to k$ then $T(f)=k$. and so any operator is closed iff its graph is closed

Comment: No problem, just be more specific on where exactly you are lost.  We will get through this. :)

Comment: but if $T$ is conts then it is closed..

Comment: If $T$ is continuous, it is closed.  If $T$ is closed it need not be continuous.  To show $T$ is closed we need to check that the graph $\{(x,Tx):x\in D\}$ is a closed subset of $D\oplus L^{2}[0,1]$.  I don't know how to do this part just yet though.

Comment: yeah, you are correct!

Comment: so do we need to show that $T$ is conts? how you do that! we only know that $f$ is equal to AC function a.e?

Comment: We need to show that $T$ is closed.  As for how, I'm still thinking about it.  As of yet I still don't know where you are lost in the first part.  One thing at a time please!

Comment: Sorry! thanx for the help!

Comment: It's no problem but you still haven't answered me. :P

Comment: ok, for the 1st part we have to use the MVT we need $g$ and $h$ to be conts , but we only have that $g$ or $h$ are AC!!

Comment: Absolutely continuity is a stronger condition than continuity.  As for the second part of your problem, we will need to use absolute continuity and some form of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.  I will get back to you by tomorrow afternoon on this.

Comment: OMG I was thinking that continuity is stronger!! Derp. thanx for the help!

Comment: This may be a helpful resource in the mean time.
http://www.ualberta.ca/~rjia/Math418/Notes/chap3.pdf

Answer (score -1):

For the first part, you need to prove that if a function equals $g$ and another function $g_1$ almost everywhere $A$ and $A_1$ respectively. Then $g$ equals almost everywhere $g_1$ ($A_1\cup A_2$). And two elements equaling almost everywhere in $L^2[0,1]$ are equal. Which gives the well defined part.

Comment: Do you mean a.e on $A$ and $A_1$?

Comment: a.e. on $[0,1]\setminus A$

Comment: oh. Ok! thanx, what about the 2nd part?

Comment: can we use "somehow" the closed graph theorem!!!!

Comment: @MarkFd: Unfortunately, the closed graph theorem applies to closed operators that are defined everywhere on a Hilbert space.  Our operator is only defined on the subset $D$, and we don't know yet whether it is closed (that's what we have to prove).